# Routing confusion on two admin in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have following routes:

```
// For user
  Route::controller('/', 'LoginController');


 //For admin
  Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
        Route::get('/', 'admin\LoginController@index');
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'admin\LoginController@show');
        Route::get('/Logout','admin\LoginController@logout');
        Route::resource('/setting','admin\SettingController');  
    });
```

I have user panel without prefix.
In logincontroller contain authorization codes.
I have found 'Controller method not found.' error when i open admin.but when i comment to user route then admin is working fine but user panel found same error.please help sir..thanks

Yes Here is LoginController of user

```
<?php
class LoginController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            return Redirect::to('/user/home');
        }
        return View::make('login.index');
    }
    public function postIndex()
    {
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');
        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]))
        {
            return Redirect::intended('/user/home');
        }
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors('Sorry,Username or password is incorrect');
    }
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
    public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::logout();

        return Redirect::to('/');
    } 
}
```

Admin Login Controller

```
<?php
namespace admin;
class LoginController extends \BaseController {
public function showLogin() {
             return \View::make('admin.login');
   }
     public function index()
     {
          return \View::make('admin.index');
     }
     public function store()
     {
               $username = \Input::get('username');
             $password = md5(\Input::get('password'));
                   if ($mm=\DB::select('select * from admin where uname = ? and password = ?', array($username, $password)))
                   {
                            \Session::put('admin', $mm);
                      return \Redirect::intended('/admin/dashboard');
               } 
               else
               {
                \Session::flush('admin');
                   return \Redirect::back()
                    ->withInput()
                    ->withErrors('Sorry,Unauthorized admin please try again');
              }
    }
      public function postIndex()
    {
         echo 'Demo of  post index';exit;
      }
    public function show()
    {
       $tt=\Session::get('admin');
       return \View::make('admin.dashboard');
    }
    public function Logout()
    {

       \Session::flush('admin');
        return \Redirect::to('/admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `LoginController`?

Comment: Yes i have place in questions please check

Comment: And the admin `LoginController`? Or are the methods the same?

Comment: No sir .i have used manual authorization using query

Comment: Then I'd like to see that too, thanks.

Comment: I have also placed now Admin Login Controller please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Route::controller('/')` is catching all requests that only have one segment. that means `/admin` as well. It then tries to find a `getAdmin()` method in the user `LoginController` which obviously doesn't exist.

You basically have two options here.

#### 1. Change the route order

Routes are searched in the order you register them. If you place the `admin` group before the other route everything will work as expected:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
    Route::get('/', 'admin\LoginController@index');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'admin\LoginController@show');
    Route::get('/Logout','admin\LoginController@logout');
    Route::resource('/setting','admin\SettingController');  
});

Route::controller('/', 'LoginController');
```

#### 2. Make explicit routes

Instead of using `Route::controller('/')` you could specify each route:

```
Route::get('/', 'LoginController@getIndex');
Route::get('login', 'LoginController@getLogin');
// etc...

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
    Route::get('/', 'admin\LoginController@index');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'admin\LoginController@show');
    Route::get('/Logout','admin\LoginController@logout');
    Route::resource('/setting','admin\SettingController');  
});
```

Comment: In admin login controller i have used backslash on every method.Can i avoid it? if yes then how?

Comment: You can add `use` statements above your class. Like `use View;`. Then you don't need the backslash anymore.